# What does 'RTU' mean?

Tags: computer-architecture

While I was reading about `Base & Bounds` memory protection mechanism, I noticed the use of the abbreviation *RTU* as indicated in the slide below:

[image]

However I didn't know what it means.

So after searching for 'RTU', I found only [this article on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Remote_terminal_unit); But I'm not sure whether it matches the term.

Does anyone have any idea?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

RTU stands for Return To User. This is invoked when the OS first accesses a physical memory range, and upon doing so will return the memory range address (code).